# Logic app file created

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-logic-apps

I am assigned to create an on-premise data gateway on a virtual machine in Azure. This way, I am able to watch new files created in a specific folder and trigger a logic app flow for every newly created file.

As the name says 'on-premise' I feel like there must be a better option.
Is there any trigger that is able to watch a certain folder on a VHD disk in a storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any trigger that is able to watch a certain folder on a VHD
>   disk in a storage account?

If my understanding is right, you want to watch files on a Azure storage account VHD. Currently, it is not possible. You need use the VHD to create a new VM or mount the VHD on a VM, then you could see the file in VHD.

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct to assume that watching files in a VHD is only possible by using the on-premise data gateway on the VM?

Comment: @Identity Yes, or you could download the VHD to your local and use Hyper to create a new VM, then you could see the files.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to fully automate the creation of the on-premise datagateway for a Azure VM with ARM? A sample template?

Comment: @Identity I find much time, I don't find any template could do this. Maybe you could install on-premise datagateway on Azure VM and use the VM create a image. Then you could create VM using the image.